# Android Runtime location permission for a service

Tags: android, gps, android-service, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am presently have a service that I use to get user location. I attach a lot of activities to it, so in case any of this activities need to get location of a user, they just call this service which will perform the task and send the location to the activity. The problem I am facing is that with marshmallow conditions of requesting for permission at run time, I don't know how to make that work. Have seen some examples here on stack overflow but they are majorly for activities not services and I still can't figure them out. 
Need help figuring it out. below is my service class and an attempted try to figure it out

```
public class GPSService extends Service implements LocationListener {

// saving the context for later use
private final Context mContext;

// if GPS is enabled
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
// if Network is enabled
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
// if Location co-ordinates are available using GPS or Network
public boolean isLocationAvailable = false;

// Location and co-ordinates coordinates
Location mLocation;
double mLatitude;
double mLongitude;

// Minimum time fluctuation for next update (in milliseconds)
private static final long TIME = 300;
// Minimum distance fluctuation for next update (in meters)
private static final long DISTANCE = 20;

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager mLocationManager;

public GPSService(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

}

/**
 * Returs the Location
 *
 * @return Location or null if no location is found
 */
public Location getLocation() {
    try {

        // Getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


        // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.


                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, TIME, DISTANCE, this);
                if (mLocationManager != null) {
                    mLocation = mLocationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (mLocation != null) {
                        mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                        mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                        isLocationAvailable = true; // setting a flag that
                        // location is available
                        return mLocation;
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we are reaching this part, it means GPS was not able to fetch
            // any location
            // Getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, TIME, DISTANCE, this);
                if (mLocationManager != null) {
                    mLocation = mLocationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (mLocation != null) {
                        mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                        mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                        isLocationAvailable = true; // setting a flag that
                        // location is available
                        return mLocation;
                    }
                }
            }
            // If reaching here means, we were not able to get location neither
            // from GPS not Network,
            if (!isGPSEnabled) {
                // so asking user to open GPS
                askUserToOpenGPS();
            }
        }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // if reaching here means, location was not available, so setting the
        // flag as false
        isLocationAvailable = false;
        return null;

}

/**
 * Gives you complete address of the location
 *
 * @return complete address in String
 */
public String getLocationAddress() {

    if (isLocationAvailable) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
        // Get the current location from the input parameter list
        // Create a list to contain the result address
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            /*
             * Return 1 address.
             */
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLatitude, mLongitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return ("IO Exception trying to get address:" + e1);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
            // Error message to post in the log
            String errorString = "Illegal arguments "
                    + Double.toString(mLatitude) + " , "
                    + Double.toString(mLongitude)
                    + " passed to address service";
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return errorString;
        }
        // If the reverse geocode returned an address
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            // Get the first address
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            /*
             * Format the first line of address (if available), city, and
             * country name.
             */
            String addressText = String.format(
                    "%s, %s, %s,%s",
                    // If there's a street address, add it
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                            .getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    // Locality is usually a city
                    address.getLocality(),
                    address.getAdminArea(),
                    // The country of the address
                    address.getCountryName());
            // Return the text
            return addressText;
        } else {
            return getString(R.string.no_address_gpsservice);
        }
    } else {
        return getString(R.string.loc_unavaliable);
    }

}



/**
 * get latitude
 *
 * @return latitude in double
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (mLocation != null) {
        mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
    }
    return mLatitude;
}

/**
 * get longitude
 *
 * @return longitude in double
 */

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if (mLocation != null) {
        mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
    }
    return mLongitude;
}

/**
 * close GPS to save battery
 */
public void closeGPS() {

    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(GPSService.this);
    }
}

/**
 * show settings to open GPS
 */
public void askUserToOpenGPS() {
    AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    mAlertDialog.setTitle(R.string.gpsservice_dialog_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.gpsservice_dialog_message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.gpsservice_dialog_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.gpsservice_dialog_negative,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).show();
}

/**
 * Updating the location when location changes
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: The activities need to check for runtime permissions, and ask for them, before starting or binding to the service.

Comment: okay let me try this

Comment: do i have to request for it in all the activities, i can just request for it once and it covers the rest

Comment: You do not know for certain exactly how the user will wind up navigating your app. Suppose you have activities A, B, and C, all of which might work with this service. A is your launcher, and A starts B, and B starts C. You might think that you only need to worry about the permissions in A. But, suppose the user navigates from A to B, then switches to the Settings app and revokes your permission. Then, the user returns to your app. The user will be given a fresh copy of **B**, and if you are not checking permissions there, you will crash.

Answer (score 0):

The best option in this moment is PermissionEverywhere library. This library allows to request a permission from any Context(Service, IntentService, etc)

https://github.com/kaknazaveshtakipishi/PermissionEverywhere